# Number of instances of application in marathon

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

Is there any way to get the number of instances of application running in marathon ? I am running a basic python webapp of 2 instances in marathon. I want to write a script to increase or decrease the number of instances automatically when the load of the mesos-slave spikes up or down. For that I need to get the applications initial no of instances running. Can someone please help on this ?

Answer (score 4):

Marathon REST API is your friend. Have a look [here](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#get-v2-apps-appid-embed-embed) and [here](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html#put-v2-apps-appid). In pseudo-python, a script you want may look something like this:

```
def scaleTo(instances, force=False):
  marathon = 'http://localhost:8080'
  url = '{}/v2/apps/<your-app-id>'.format(marathon)
  headers = {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
  params = {'force': 'true' if force else 'false'}
  payload = {'instances': instances}

  r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, params=params, json=payload, verify=False)

  r.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interested in auto scaling applications on Marathon. Take a look at [marathon-autoscale](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-autoscale) repository. Those scripts might be useful although those are just for PoC.